# PHP dynamical conditional post display

Tags: categories, query-posts

I'm trying to get the WordPress loop to display only the post has an ID that reflects whatever `$category_name` is equal to, as shown in the line of code below. It ends up showing everything and not the specified post.

```
<?php
$link=$_GET['link'];

if ($link == '1') {
    $category_name= 'accomodatins';
}
if ($link == '2'){
    $category_name= 'accomodatins1';
}
if ($link == '3'){
    $category_name= 'accomodatins2';
}
if ($link == '4'){
    $category_name= 'accomodatins3';
}
?>
```

Below is the compete code

```
?>
<ul>
    <li><a href="?link=1">Accommodations</a></li>
    <li><a href="?link=2">Accountants</a></li> <?php
</ul>
<?php

global $link;

$link = $category_name;

// assign the variable as current category

$category_name = $link;

// concatenate the query

$args = 'category_name=' . $category_name;

// run the query

query_posts( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

    // do something here

    the_content( __('Read the rest of this page »', 'template'));

    endwhile; 
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<div id="mainSection">

<!-- End Mid-Box -->
<?php
$link=$_GET['link'];
if ($link == '1'){
    $category_name= 'accomodatins';
}
if ($link == '2'){
    cat_switcher();
}
if ($link == '3'){
    cat_switcher();
}
if ($link == '4'){
    cat_switcher();
}
?>

</div>
```

Comment: In what context is this loop? How is `link` defined/added to the URL string?

Comment: Toooo much white space...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is disjointed, but from the look of it you are passing an `ID` as the `category_name` value. The switch that would convert that to a name comes after the query.

Move this, or something like it,...

```
$link=$_GET['link'];
if ($link == '1'){
    $category_name= 'accomodatins';
}
if ($link == '2'){
   cat_switcher();
}
if ($link == '3'){
    cat_switcher();
}
if ($link == '4'){
    cat_switcher();
}
```

... up so that it is before the query and thus converts `$link` which is a number to a name.

Also, [don't use `query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts). Create a new [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) object or use a filter on [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts)